# c# unhandled exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have a problem with an array of classes. basically I create an array of the class 'Student', but I cannot assign values to any properties of the instances in the array because I get the unhandled exception in the title. here's the code:

```
class ControllerQueue
{
    model.ModelStudent q = new model.ModelStudent();

    static int capacity = 15;
    model.ModelStudent[] arr = new model.ModelStudent[capacity];
    int top = -1, rear = 0;

    public ControllerQueue()
    {
        arr[0].name = "a";
        arr[0].grade = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried assigning values out of the constructor, but I still get the same result. now, the exception itself obviously sais I didn't instantiate the Student class but I don't understand why it would say that, I've already instantiated it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to instantiate the members of your array

add the item to your array like this

```
arr[0] = new ModelStudent();
arr[0].name = "a";
arr[0].grade = 0;
```

Comment: thanks to all of you, but unfortunately I can only select 1 best answer:d.. I'm just learning my way around c#. thanks a bunch again.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
arr[0] = new ModelStudent();
arr[0].name = "a";
arr[0].grade = 0;
```

You need this because you have to `new` up an instance to put into the array at index 0

```
model.ModelStudent[] arr = new model.ModelStudent[capacity];
```

Will just allocate the array, but each entry is by default the default value of ModelStudent `(null)`

Answer (score 1):

Your item 0 is not set.

Try.

```
model.ModelStudent q = new model.ModelStudent();

        static int capacity = 15;
        model.ModelStudent[] arr = new model.ModelStudent[capacity];
        int top = -1, rear = 0;


        public ControllerQueue()
        {
            arr[0] = new model.ModelStudent();
            arr[0].name = "a";
            arr[0].grade = 0;
        }
```

Comment: @Tim: nowadays seniors architects make basic syntax (and conceptual) mistakes too often. I find it funny.

Comment: @zerkms - Ok.  Maybe it's because it's Sunday evening for me, but I'm not seeing any mistakes in the code Nico posted.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: @Tim: it was edited within 5 minutes. Stackoverflow doesn't track such modifications

Comment: @zerkms - Ah.  Thanks - thought I was missing something obvious.